# Is there a more optimal way to create this view or stored procedure? Currently using a cross apply, but it's slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, stored-procedures, cross-apply

***I've updated this post with some test data.***

I'm creating a report for my Movies database where I'd like for the end-user to be able to select movies of a certain genre. However, some movies have multiple genres and I've normalized the database so that a movie line item that had more than one genre turns into multiple line items, each pointing to the respective genre/genreID. (A similar thing has been done for directors).

**Before Normalization**

| Movie | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| Bride of Frankenstein | Horror, Drama |

**After Normalization**

| Movie | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| Bride of Frankenstein | Horror |
| Bride of Frankenstein | Drama |

The problem that I have is, for the sake of this report, I would like to make it so that the movies do not repeat in the report if they have multiple genres. But rather, the movie title becomes one line item and the genres field is concatenated to show all of the genres within the one line (similar to the before normalization view). What I've ended up doing is creating a view where I cross apply the output of the movie selection by the genres that match the movie ID. I feel like I've overcomplicated it a bit and my stores procedure is running pretty slow, as I have a couple of other fields that I am allowing the user to filter on as well.

Here's a look at the cross apply view.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwMoviesJoinedGenres] AS

WITH genreMovies_CTE AS (
SELECT M.MovieID
    , M.MovieTitle
    , G.GenreName
    , G.GenreID
    , M.TitleTypeID
    , TT.TitleType
    , M.MediaID
    , M.IMDBLink
    , M.IMDBRating
    , M.ReleaseDate
    , M.Runtime
    , M.ImageURL
    , M.MovieYear
FROM [dbo].[Movies] AS M
INNER JOIN GenresMovies AS GM
    ON GM.MovieID = M.MovieID
INNER JOIN Genres AS G
    ON G.GenreID = GM.GenreID
INNER JOIN TitleType AS TT
    ON TT.TitleTypeID = M.TitleTypeID
)   
SELECT 
    DISTINCT MovieID, ImageURL, MovieYear, MovieTitle, TitleType, SUBSTRING(G.genres, 0, 
    LEN(G.genres)) AS Genres, GenreID, TitleTypeID, MediaID, IMDBLink, IMDBRating, ReleaseDate, 
    Runtime
FROM genreMovies_CTE
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT DISTINCT GenreName + ', ' 
    FROM Genres AS G
    INNER JOIN GenresMovies AS GM ON GM.GenreID = G.GenreID
    WHERE genreMovies_CTE.MovieID = GM.MovieID
    FOR XML PATH('')        
) G(genres)
GO
```

I then use this view (and a similar view for directors) in the stored procedure below.

```
USE [Movies]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--====================================================
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MovieByGenreUsingViews] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @GenreID nvarchar(255)
    , @MediaID nvarchar(255)
    , @TitleTypeID nvarchar(255)
WITH RECOMPILE

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH genresMovies_CTE AS
(SELECT 
    DISTINCT JG.[MovieID]
    , JG.[MovieTitle]
    , JG.Genres
    , JG.[TitleTypeName]
    , JG.[TitleTypeID]
    , JG.[MediaID]
    , Me.MediaType
    , JD.Directors
FROM [dbo].[vwMoviesJoinedGenres] AS JG --JoinedGenres
INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwMoviesJoinedDirectors] AS JD
    ON JG.MovieID = JD.movieID
INNER JOIN Media AS Me
    ON Me.MediaTypeID = JG.MediaTypeID
WHERE GenreID IN (SELECT Number FROM [fn_SplitInt](@GenreID, ','))
    AND JG.MediaTypeID IN (SELECT Number FROM [fn_SplitInt](@MediaID, ',')) 
    AND JG.TitleTypeID IN (SELECT Number FROM [fn_SplitInt](@TitleTypeID, ',')) 
)
SELECT MovieTitle, Genres, Directors, TitleType, MediaType
FROM genresMovies_CTE
ORDER BY movietitle

END
```

****Updating with a very small sample data set as requested. I've simplified a lot obviously to save time and have decided to focus on Genres only.**

Creating Tables and Inserting Data

```
USE [Test Movies];
GO
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MovieDetails;
CREATE TABLE MovieDetails 
(
    MovieID int NOT NULL 
    , MovieTitle nvarchar(255)
    , Constraint MovieID PRIMARY KEY (MovieID)
);

--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genres;
CREATE TABLE Genres(
      GenreID tinyint NOT NULL Identity(1,1)
    , GenreName varchar(50) NOT NULL 
    , CONSTRAINT GenreID PRIMARY KEY (GenreID)
)

--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MovieGenre;
CREATE TABLE MovieGenre
(
    MovieID int NOT NULL
    , GenreID tinyint NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT GenresMovies PRIMARY KEY (MovieID, GenreID)
);

INSERT INTO MovieDetails (MovieID, MovieTitle)
VALUES
(1, 'Forest Gump')
, (2, 'Eyes Wide Shut')
, (3, 'Kelly''s Heroes')
, (4, 'Where Eagles Dare')
, (5, 'Star Trek: First Contact')
, (6, 'The Ten Commandments')
, (7, 'Clash of the Titans')
, (8, 'AVP: Alien vs. Predator')
, (9, 'Batman Returns')
, (10, 'Crash')

INSERT INTO Genres (GenreName)
VALUES ('Drama'), ('Adventure'), ('Family'), ('Horror'), ('Crime');

INSERT INTO MovieGenre (MovieID, GenreID)
VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,2), 
(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2), (7,2), 
(7,3), (8,4), (9,5), (10,1);
```

**Code to splitInt Function found online**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitInt]
(
    @List       nvarchar(4000),
    @Delimiter  char(1)= ','
)
RETURNS @Values TABLE
(
    Position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Number int
)

AS

  BEGIN

  -- set up working variables
  DECLARE @Index INT
  DECLARE @ItemValue nvarchar(100)
  SELECT @Index = 1 

  -- iterate until we have no more characters to work with
  WHILE @Index > 0

    BEGIN

      -- find first delimiter
      SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List)

      -- extract the item value
      IF @Index  > 0     -- if found, take the value left of the delimiter
        SELECT @ItemValue = LEFT(@List,@Index - 1)
      ELSE               -- if none, take the remainder as the last value
        SELECT @ItemValue = @List

      -- insert the value into our new table
      INSERT INTO @Values (Number) VALUES (CAST(@ItemValue AS int))

      -- remove the found item from the working list
      SELECT @List = RIGHT(@List,LEN(@List) - @Index)

      -- if list is empty, we are done
      IF LEN(@List) = 0 BREAK

    END

  RETURN

  END
```

**Joining Genres using STRING_AGG**

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MovieByGenreStrAgg] 
    @GenreID nvarchar(255)
WITH RECOMPILE

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT DISTINCT 
      movieTitleID.movieID
    , movieTitleID.movietitle
    , movieTitleID.genres 
FROM
(SELECT 
      MD.MovieID
    , MD.MovieTitle
    , STRING_AGG(G.GenreName, ', ') AS Genres
FROM MovieDetails AS MD
INNER JOIN MovieGenre AS MG 
    ON MG.MovieID = MD.MovieID
INNER JOIN Genres AS G 
    ON G.GenreID = MG.GenreID
GROUP BY MD.MovieID, MD.MovieTitle) 
AS movieTitleID
INNER JOIN MovieGenre AS MG 
    ON MG.MovieID = movieTitleID.MovieID
INNER JOIN Genres AS G 
    ON G.GenreID = MG.GenreID
WHERE G.GenreID IN (SELECT Number FROM [fn_SplitInt](@GenreID, ','))

END
```

**Joining Genres using Cross Apply**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MovieByGenreCrsApply] 
    @GenreID nvarchar(255)
WITH RECOMPILE

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
      movieTitleID.MovieID
    , movieTitleID.MovieTitle
    , SUBSTRING(G.genres, 0, LEN(G.genres)) AS genres
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
              MovieID
            , MovieTitle
        FROM MovieDetails
    
    ) 
    AS movieTitleID
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT G.GenreName + ', '
    FROM Genres AS G
    INNER JOIN MovieGenre AS MG
        ON MG.GenreID = G.GenreID
    WHERE movieTitleID.MovieID = MG.MovieID 
        AND G.GenreID IN (SELECT Number FROM [fn_SplitInt](@GenreID, ','))
    FOR XML PATH('')        
    ) G(genres)
    WHERE G.genres IS NOT NULL; 
END
```

When I executed the separate statements, I noticed something I hadn't before.

exec [usp_MovieByGenreStrAgg] '2,3' -- where 2 is Adventure, 3 is Family

| MovieID | MovieTitle | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Kelly's Heroes | Adventure |
| 4 | Where Eagles Dare | Adventure |
| 5 | Star Trek: First Contact | Drama, Adventure |
| 6 | The Ten Commandments | Drama, Adventure |
| 7 | Clash of the Titans | Adventure, Family |

exec [usp_MovieByGenreCrsApply] '2,3' -- where 2 is Adventure, 3 is Family

| MovieID | MovieTitle | Genres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Kelly's Heroes | Adventure |
| 4 | Where Eagles Dare | Adventure |
| 5 | Star Trek: First Contact | Adventure |
| 6 | The Ten Commandments | Adventure |
| 7 | Clash of the Titans | Adventure, Family |

String_Agg returns all of the genres of a given movie whose genre has been selected, even if only one of the genres were selected as a parameter value. Cross apply returned only the genres that were selected. I realized I prefer when it displays only the genres I'm interested in.

However, I noticed that when I save my cross apply in a view first and then apply the parameters, it behaves effectively like my String_Agg procedure. I think I prefer the way cross applies behaves (without having to save it in a view first), but I'm pretty sure that it's much slower this way without a view, so back at square one with the sloweness. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? if 2017 or greater, you can use STRING_AGG. Otherwise, is this something you can handle in the reporting tool, rather than doing string manipulation in SQL, which is always prone to performance problems?

Comment: Could you please update your post to include some information on your current runtimes, and a link to the **actual execution plan**? (You can use [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) to upload it.)

Comment: `[fn_SplitInt](@GenreID, ',')` No idea what this does nor how you expect it to be useful. The datatype of that parameter (like all the others) is tinyint so I fail to see how it could be "split". Use of DISTINCT is questionable. But you seem to have a [kitchen-sink report](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) coupled with a need to pass a [list as a parameter](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html).

Comment: @HandyD, not sure if there’s a better way to do this in SSRS. I will take a look into string_agg.

Comment: @J.D., I’ll update with an execution plan later today. I won’t have computer access fit most of the day.

Comment: @SMor, I made a bad update on the fly before I submitted this question. Those IDs should all be Nvarchar. I want to have the ability for multi select, I want to be able to convert a string of multiple values (“1,2,3,4”) into individual values to check against the values in my genre, title type and media tables. The split function is being used to split the string into multiple int values. Also, I used distinct because in my JoinedGenres view, I need to I return a genreID in addition to a movieID, which means that for every genre the movie is repeated, so I specify distinct in the Procedure.

Comment: The posted links demonstrate exactly how to do that and also discuss the problems (and solutions) to the poor-performance aspect. And consider what actually happens (vs. what is desired) when at least one of the search parameters for your procedure contains nothing.

Comment: And since movie genres will not be changing generally, you might consider the benefit of simply pre-aggregating those values into a table. That is a small denormalization that might be worth the cost of space and a little processor work during DML. In addition, you over-complicate by trying to do too much in too many places. Suggest your view simply sticks to the aggregation of genres ONLY - allowing it to be used anywhere that wants a single row per movie with all related genres in a single column.

Comment: @SMor, I’ll take some more time to review your response later this evening. Pre-aggregating in a table is something that I considered, so that may make some sense. Thank you.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you could provide a [mcve] with the relevant table structure since that would allow us to easily repro the issue and provide the best possible answer.

Comment: I'll update my post with more details (I should have a lot of time this weekend). But just wanted to add, I think String_Agg is the way to go (thanks @HandyD). In about 2 seconds it returns data (when I select ALL genres, media, and title types). In about 4 seconds, cross apply does the same. I cleared data cache in between each run. I have to play around with it a little more. FYI, I did an upgrade of visual studio and I'm not sure if I'm imaging it, but my queries seemed to be overall faster. Want to do some more validation before posting what I've come up with. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I updated my post with some more details and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Having your split function inside an `APPLY` is a bad idea.  It potentially could be evaluated over and over, killing performance.  You should put those values in a temp table or table variable.

Your `STRING_AGG` is returning categories other than those you selected because you are building the list, then filter (via the additional joins and where clause. Move the `WHERE` clause inside the grouping and you will only get the categories you selected.

In either case, you can simplify your queries a fair amount.  Here is some POC code for either style ('just selected' or 'all'):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MovieDetails
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Genres
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MovieGenre


CREATE TABLE #MovieDetails 
(
    MovieID int NOT NULL 
    , MovieTitle nvarchar(255)
    , Constraint MovieID PRIMARY KEY (MovieID)
);

--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genres;
CREATE TABLE #Genres(
      GenreID tinyint NOT NULL Identity(1,1)
    , GenreName varchar(50) NOT NULL 
    , CONSTRAINT GenreID PRIMARY KEY (GenreID)
)

--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MovieGenre;
CREATE TABLE #MovieGenre
(
    MovieID int NOT NULL
    , GenreID tinyint NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT GenresMovies PRIMARY KEY (MovieID, GenreID)
);

INSERT INTO #MovieDetails (MovieID, MovieTitle)
VALUES
(1, 'Forest Gump')
, (2, 'Eyes Wide Shut')
, (3, 'Kelly''s Heroes')
, (4, 'Where Eagles Dare')
, (5, 'Star Trek: First Contact')
, (6, 'The Ten Commandments')
, (7, 'Clash of the Titans')
, (8, 'AVP: Alien vs. Predator')
, (9, 'Batman Returns')
, (10, 'Crash')

INSERT INTO #Genres (GenreName)
VALUES ('Drama'), ('Adventure'), ('Family'), ('Horror'), ('Crime');

INSERT INTO #MovieGenre (MovieID, GenreID)
VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,2), 
(5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2), (7,2), 
(7,3), (8,4), (9,5), (10,1);


DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2,3'

DECLARE @idsXML XML = TRY_CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(ISNULL(@ids, ''), ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)
DECLARE @idTable AS TABLE(id INT)

INSERT INTO @idTable
SELECT TRY_CAST(i.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS INT) FROM @idsXML.nodes('//i') X(i)

SELECT 
    m.MovieID, m.MovieTitle, STRING_AGG(g.GenreName, ',') Genres 
FROM #MovieDetails m 
    JOIN #MovieGenre mg ON m.MovieID = mg.MovieID 
    JOIN #Genres g ON g.GenreID = mg.GenreID
    JOIN @idTable i ON g.GenreID = i.id
GROUP BY m.MovieID, m.MovieTitle

SELECT 
    m.MovieID, m.MovieTitle, STRING_AGG(g.GenreName, ',') Genres 
FROM #MovieDetails m 
    JOIN #MovieGenre mg ON m.MovieID = mg.MovieID 
    JOIN #Genres g ON g.GenreID = mg.GenreID
WHERE m.MovieID IN (SELECT MovieID FROM #MovieGenre mg JOIN @idTable i ON mg.GenreID = i.id)
GROUP BY m.MovieID, m.MovieTitle
```

You could fancy too...

```
DECLARE @allMode  BIT = 0

SELECT 
    m.MovieID, m.MovieTitle, STRING_AGG(g.GenreName, ',') Genres 
FROM #MovieDetails m 
    JOIN #MovieGenre mg ON m.MovieID = mg.MovieID 
    JOIN #Genres g ON g.GenreID = mg.GenreID
    LEFT JOIN @idTable i ON g.GenreID = i.id
WHERE (m.MovieID IN (SELECT MovieID FROM #MovieGenre mg JOIN @idTable i ON mg.GenreID = i.id) AND @allMode = 1)
    OR (i.id IS NOT NULL AND @allMode = 0)
GROUP BY m.MovieID, m.MovieTitle
```

Comment: No... having a split function in the CROSS APPLY isn't a problem... having THAT split function anywhere is the problem.  Any split function that uses a CURSOR, WHILE loop, "XML splitter" or a "JSON splitter" should never be used anywhere for splitting strings based on a delimiter.

Comment: You are free to your own opinion, but it is not one I share.  String splitting in SQL Server is a bonified need at times and is appropriately expensive under the right circumstances. Awareness of the expense and avoidance of unneeded expenses is very important, but it seems that is too nuanced for your worldview.

Comment: I believe you mistook what I was saying.  It's not a bad thing to have a good split function in a CROSS APPLY.  It IS a bad thing to have any split function that consists of the items I mentioned in my first comment above.